# View linked Assembly source for NASM linked file in C++

Tags: c++, gdb, nasm

I have a C++ program (main.cpp) that calls an Assembly function.
`extern "C" size_t my_func(char*, char, size_t);`
The asm source file is `Example.nasm`
The compiled program is `example`

I would like to view the execution of the Assembly function (using source code and also seeing the registers).

The program itself is compiled using cmake. However, I assembled using NASM with dwarf and stabs to generate object files with debugging symbols.

`nasm -f elf64 -F stabs -g example.nasm`

I set the break point at my_func:
`break my_func`

Using
`frame function my_func`

I can see the registers and compiled assembly i.e. `layout split`.
However, GDB didn't show the source code - and said it couldn't find it.
Using `show directories` in GDB to list the path, I saw that `..` needed to be added.
I added the actual working directory using  `directory ..`
This then shows the C++ source code calling the assembly but not the assembly source.

[This [reference](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/gdb-source-path/) is very helpful for anyone else troubleshooting GDB and how it identifies source files.]

How might I point GDB to the asm source code in this instance?

Comment: You are absolutely sure you get the same behavior using `-F dwarf` like `nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf example.nasm` ?

Comment: Yes, also because I typically compile with -F dwarf. I'd only tried stabs because of a comment elsewhere.